# JavaScript window object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, window

In JavaScript, let's say we have a main page (`main.html`) which contains an `<iframe>` (`iframe.html`).

Now inside this `iframe.html`, if we need to refer to something on the main page (`main.html`), can we not just specify `window` instead of `parent.window`.

If the answer is we need to write `parent.window`, I wanted to understand is there not a single `window` object reference for all the iframes within a main page...

While I do understand `document` is specific to individual iframes, but `window` should be common to all..Isn't it...Please help me in understanding the concept...

Also is there something `window.parent` as well? If yes, how does it differ from `parent.window`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The concept of `window` is tied to the `document`: There's one `window` per `document`, and one `document` per `window`.

That means `<iframe>` elements, which have their own `document`, also have their own `window`, just like a pop-up window or the main navigator window.

So, you'll indeed have to use `window.parent` to access the container of an `<iframe>` element, just like you have to use `window.opener` to access the owner of a pop-up window.

**EDIT:** Both `window.parent` and `parent.window` are valid expressions that return the same object. That's because the `window` object is the *default context* in scripting (unqualified names are parsed as members of `window`), and `window` objects have a `window` property that refers to themselves.

So, `parent.window` is evaluated as `window.parent.window`, which is the same object as `window.parent`.

That said, I do prefer using `window.parent`, to avoid the (minimal) overhead associated with the extra property access.

Comment: Do I have to use window.parent to access the container OR parent.window OR both are valid?

Comment: @hmthr I recommend `window.window.parent.window.window`... `:)`

Comment: @hmthr: in JavaScript on browsers, The window object is the container of all global variables. In fact, the `window` symbol is, itself, a property of the window object (referring back to the object). `parent` is also a property of the window object, and so `window.parent` is redundant, you can just say `parent`. However, it's useful for being clear about what you're doing. `parent.window` will also work, but in a misleading way: The `parent` part gives you your parent window's window object, no need to go further; and then you're looking up the `window` prop on it (which refers back to it).

Comment: @Sime: I think you forgot a `self` somewhere in there ;)

Comment: `There's one window per document, and one document per window`. If you are right, then what is `window.history`? As W3C says, `window` object is a wrapper for many documents, first of which is `about:blank` document, which would be associated with the window object on its creation. This is the concept of [`browsing context`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#windows).

Comment: @Saeed, `window.history` refers to a `History` object that, in turn, references the documents in the session history. These documents are not directly associated with the window. The same `History` object is part of browsing contexts, and the link you provide indeed documents a special case, but the general case is a one-to-one mapping between documents and windows.

Comment: From the link: `In general, there is a 1-to-1 mapping from the Window object to the Document object. In one particular case, a Window can be reused for the presentation of a second Document in the same browsing context, such that the mapping is then 2-to-1. This occurs when a browsing context is navigated from the initial about:blank Document to another, with replacement enabled.`

Answer (score 13):

`iframe`s (and `frame`s) are their own windows, even though in the case of `iframe`s they look like they're part of the main document's window. So yes, to refer to the main document's window, they'd use `parent` (or `window.parent` if you want to be verbose, but clear), because they are separate objects. This is partially necessary because a lot of the things in `document` end up as properties on the containing `window`.

If you think about it, it makes sense: The purpose of an `iframe` is to embed independently-sourced content within the page. If the main page and the `iframe`(s) on it shared a single `window` object, they'd be sharing global context, and quite possibly conflicting with one another.

Gratuitous [live example](http://jsbin.com/ivimay):

Parent's HTML:

```
<p>I'm the parent window</p>
<iframe width="500" height="500" src="http://jsbin.com/iyogir"></iframe>
```

Parent's JavaScript:

```
function foo() {
  display("<code>foo</code> called!");
}
function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Child's HTML:

```
<p>I'm in the frame</p>
<input type='button' id='theButton' value='Click Me'>
```

Child's JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('theButton').onclick = function() {
    var p = window.parent;
    if (!p) {
      display("Can't find parent window");
    }
    else if (typeof p.foo !== "function") {
      display("Found parent window, but can't find <code>foo</code> function on it");
    }
    else {
      display("Calling parent window's <code>foo</code> function.");
      p.foo();
    }
  };

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }

};
```