# Does jQuery inside an IFRAME affect the parent window's jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've read about "[Can javascript running inside an iframe affect the main page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951946/)" and understand that it *is* possible from within an IFRAME to modify JavaScript variables of the parent window.

What I do not yet understand is how/whether different jQuery versions can co-exist if my IFRAME is not out to be manipulating the parent window.

[image]

I have to support different browser like IE 9+, Firefox, Google Chrome.

**My question:**

Does an IFRAME with a higher jQuery affect in any way the jQuery behaviour of the parent HTML page?

*(The IFRAME comes from a different domain than the main page)*

Comment: @Jai Different ones, e.g. IE 9+, Firefox, Google Chrome.

Comment: You mentioned that the iframe come from different domains. Isnt'it ?! so the approach you need to use is far more complex that usual. Look  at this for example: http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls

Comment: @pinturic Thanks. I do _not_ want to manipulate. I want to know if both jQuery versions can co-exist _without_ affecting each other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I've read about "Can javascript running inside an iframe affect the
>   main page?" and understand that it is possible from within an IFRAME
>   to modify JavaScript variables of the parent window

This is true, but only if the frame is on the same domain as the parent. And even then, the `iframe` would have to explicitly access the variable using `window.parent` or similar.

If the iframe is on a different domain, you can't modify the parent anyway.

> Does an IFRAME with a higher jQuery affect in any way the jQuery
>   behaviour of the parent HTML page?

jQuery stores itself as `window.jQuery` (or `window.$`) which is a reference to the [*current* document's window only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679406/javascript-window-object#answer-6679433)*, this will not modify the parent iframe in any way either on same-domain or cross-domain. So you can have different versions of jQuery on both the inner & outer frames and they will not conflict.

<sub>* This links to a superb answer from TJ Crowder which explains the differences of the `window` object in terms of `<iframe>` elements - much better than I ever could.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> Does an IFRAME with a higher jQuery affect in any way the jQuery
>   behaviour of the parent HTML page?

As answered by @RGraham, by itself this will cause no conflict and they can happily co-exist as they belong to different browsing contexts.

However, theoretically there may be edge cases where ***your usage*** may affect it.

Consider a scenario where both your `iframe` sources are in the same domain (perhaps different apps which you want to seamlessly surface). Say, your parent app references older version of jQuery and the child app references a newer version. Now, you can call methods on the parent version from your child. Perhaps a use-case where you cannot change anything in the parent app, but want to just use method calls from the child. In such a case, you have to be careful not to end up calling a defunct method on the parent.

For example,

**Parent** (Referencing older version of jQuery)

```
<html>
    <head><script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Parent</h1>
        <input id="chk" type="checkbox">
        <iframe src="child.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Child** (Referencing newer version of jQuery)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function($) {
                console.log("Attr: " + parent.$("#chk").attr("checked"));
                console.log("Prop from child: " + $("#chk", parent.document).prop("checked"));
                console.log("Prop from parent: " + parent.$("#chk").prop("checked"));
            } (window.jQuery));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Child</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result**:

```
Attr: false
Prop from child: false
Uncaught TypeError: parent.$(...).prop is not a function
```

As you can see, that the last test will throw up. This is because the method `prop` is not available with the older version.

In short, you have to be careful to avoid such edge cases and use the document content context rather than the Javascript context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable input!